# Difference between Lumia 525 and 526?

Tags: lumia

What are the difference between Lumia 525 and Lumia 526 ? Which model is better among these two?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The phones are very similar, except that the 526 is designed for networks using [TD-SCDMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TD-SCDMA). As far as I can tell TD-SCDMA networks are available in China only.